# Free hand draw on axes with high number of point per second

Tags: matlab, drawing, handwriting, pen

I am working on a handwriting recognition project using Matlab.

The first picture totally contains 450points because it was written slowly.

The second picture contains only 56points because it was written in a fast speed.

As we can see, when writing speed is fast, we can get fewer pixel points. However, when we write slowly, we can get more pixel points.

How can we get more pixel points when user writing in a fast speed ? For example, 1200points per second.

[image: Slow speed writing]

Pic1 : Slow speed writing

[image: Fast speed writing]

Pic2 : Fast speed writing